# Split the "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community" to reflect off topic questions

Tags: feature-request, meta, close-reasons

##Background
A [recent question from a disgruntled user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204541/how-does-rudeness-and-censorship-promote-learning-on-stackoverflow) (10K only) brought up one fair point (and a **lot** of noise). The "This question does not appear to seek input" is while clear, not *blatantly* clear when used to close questions which are completely off topic (and not obviously about programming, or a terrible programming question that people don't want to suggest goes to stack overflow).

The first use of this close reason (rants, and general posts of peoples opinions) is correct and the description fits it perfectly:

> This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the
> community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites,
> please describe it in detail. See also: What is "meta"? How does it
> work?

However when used to close off topic questions a reading may go as:

> > "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the
> > community"
>
> Yes it does, I want the community to answer my question about hard drives, see I said so
>
> > "If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe
> > it in detail. See also: What is "meta"? How does it work?"

> I'm new to stack exchange so I have no idea what you're talking about,
> what is meta? I've stopped listening.

##Proposal
Add another close reason for "is not about the stack exchange sites" of;

> This question does not appear to be about the website Stack Overflow or the Stack Exchange network of sites. It may be on topic on [another site in the stack exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) or may be off topic across the entire network. See also: [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta)

##Reasoning
At present we only have 3 custom close reasons so fitting in a forth doesn't seem too much and at present the "This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community" is doing 2 very different jobs, one very well (rants, statements of opinion) and one less well (off topic questions that below on another site), where it is covered, but only by implication and reading links.

I feel that all that noise and ranting may have been avoided had a slightly more clear close reason been available.

Comment: Who am I kidding that rant was always going to happen unless the stack exchange team arrived at their house to personally solve the problem

Comment: Either that, or rephrase the "programming questions" one in such a way that you don't feel like you end up recommending SO for crap. I now often grasp for the "not seeking input" one because I don't want to use the other one.

Comment: @Bart Agreed. I was going to say that the original question was just closed for the wrong reason, but then I saw that I cast the closing vote.  I don't want to encourage people to copy/paste a crappy question to Stack Overflow just to watch it get closed there too.

Comment: @Bart or both.  I've long felt the "doesn't seek input" isn't clear enough for the people that it targets (those who don't know what meta is) so I go to the programming one more than I should simply because of that

Comment: Re the link, loooooool. That said, I agree that "doesn't seek input" is clear enough.

Comment: @probablyPekka The version that you see there is heavily sanitised by me as well. There was a lot more ranting about how Ripoff report would bring us all down before

Comment: @Richard the ripoff report really is gold.

Comment: @prob Read the "report" (read: rant); it's the funniest thing I've read all day :D also, see revision 1 of that question, before Richard's improvements it was at least 10 times worse EDIT: dang it, I hate commenting from my phone and not seeing live responses

Comment: @RichardTingle BTW your edit to that post was pure genius.  You actually make it worth salvaging if it wasn't for the OP not desiring a constructive conversation and just wanted to rant about how we mistreated him and we need to be nice to him.

Comment: And if anybody deletes that comment I'm filing a RipoffReport on your asses!

Comment: @Won't I don't necessarily disagree that the absence of Karl from stack overflow probably won't hurt it, if anything people were remarkably patient with him. He did make one good point however (amongst a firestorm of noise)

Comment: Now the close reason on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204570/do-you-know-a-forum-for-mechanical-engineering) seems a good canditate for this, however I can't find it in the reasons. Perhaps its an "other" but I see it often

Comment: @RichardTingle That was an "other" reason I mostly copied from the SO reason (hence why it looks familiar), but with a few edits.

Comment: Also am kind of pissed that I missed the drama [because I could have dropped this image from my profile on him](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4A248.png).

Comment: @Won't that's globalization for ya - it happened during the wrong time. Maybe Meta should be closed overnight (ET) so we never miss stuff like this

Answer (score 8):

I agree it wouldn't hurt to do something about this.

Perhaps it might suffice to amend the current close reason though:

> This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community **on an issue related to Stack Exchange or one of its sites.** If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail. See also: What is "meta"? How does it work?

Comment: I just think that this close reason isn't well suited for "completely offtopic" questions, but rather questions not actually asking a question, or not asking one constructively.  Using one close reason to handle several completely unrelated problems was the reason for the close system overhaul in the first place.  With this wording appropriate meta questions that are not actually seeking input will be confused by that added line, and completely offtopic questions like the referenced question will still be confused by the first phrase.

Comment: @Servy yeah, fair point (and it's not like adding a close reason in the dialog would add more complexity)